Does "can" work here even though it's about a future result?
"If the new equipment works well, the manager can reduce the production costs by 30% in the first quarter of 2025."
Does "can" work here although it's referring to a result in the future?

Yes, that is a valid use of "can".  Generally, you can say "I can do it tomorrow." On the other hand, "will can" is always incorrect.  If you want to put explicit tense into the verb, then "will be able to" is an alternative (and makes no difference to the meaning in this example)
